# No Keyboard Input in VirtualBox 4.1

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox

I've just installed virtualbox from the 12.10 repo and I'm finding that there is no keyboard input (although the host key works) on the boot screen of the guest OS.

The guest OS is a recent version of Debian. The machine boots and then hangs on the boot menu.

My host and guest are both 64bit.

Are there any issues with keyboard input surrounding virtualbox on Ubuntu 12.10 at the moment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File>Preferences>Input and unchecking 'Auto Capture Keyboard' seems to have fixed this issue.

Comment: Are there any additional steps other than unchecking? This isn't working for me. Host: ubuntu 14.04, guest: rhel5